# Column filter in data table

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

Hope you are all doing good.

I am trying to use react-data-table-component from jbetancur (https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component#readme) and i would like to implement the following:

Currently i have this:

[image: What i have]

And i want to get this:

[image]

So, to resume what i want is to have a filter option for every (or not) column. I want to have the possibility to give a column the ability to filter by that column.

I have checked the documentation and made some searches but didn't get anything, so i'm unsure if this will be possible.

If you need anymore info to help, just tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need this answer. Someone did answer you? how do you solved it?